# Are old spells still useful after obtaining a new one?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

In other words: Is the last spell obtained always the stronger one and are there any reasons to use old spells ? (Like are some monsters more vulnerable to a specific element)

I'm currently using the lightning spell (I don't know if there are more spells).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal preference really. They all do the same thing, in different ways. As far as I have seen anyway, meaning I don't believe specific enemies have any weaknesses to specific spells.

Only reason that you need all three is that there is a point in the game you require the lighting and fire spells.

That being said, the Fire spell causes burn damage, but that is a chance to initiate (enemies don't always get burned after you cast the spell).

You get the Fire spell

> after you defeat the first boss. (The Moonblood).

---

**Post-note:** There is one Achievement/Trophy that is easily obtainable with the use of the Default, or the Lightning Spell

> which can be obtained after defeating Lady Tethys.

called *"That's More Like It!" - Get a combo of 1000 hits or more*. This can be achieved in several places with some skill, but the easiest place is against the two tree-men (as seen in this video):

or in the sorrowing meadows, where the enemies are never ending. (This does take a bit more skill, as they are spread out and keeping the combo alive can be tricky).

Comment: So there is not significant damage difference between spells?

Comment: No unfortunately.

Comment: Combo potential does increase with new spells, though.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson How's that?

Comment: For the post note, I believe there is an item that will reduce all of your stats *significantly* which will make getting that achievement/trophy even *easier*.